# How to fit a long equation in a table in latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

Here is the code for the table I've written

```
\begin{table}[H]

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
{Case}&{Analytical Expressions}\\
\hline

\hline
$C_{11}$ & $\begin{multlined} 
\rho_{+}=\frac{\begin{multlined}(sin^2{2\theta_{12}}c_{12}^2c_{23}^4-s_{13}^2s_{23}^2c_{12}^2c_{23}^2cos^2{\delta}(2(1+s_{12}^2)-cos{2\theta_{12}})^2-c_{12}^2c_{23}^2s_{23}^2s_{13}^2(4c_{23}sin{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}(1+s_{12}^2)\\-2s_{23}^2s_{13}-2c_{23}cos{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}-s_{23}s_{13}cos{2\delta}+s_{23}s_{13}cos^2{2\theta_{12}}cos{2\delta}-8s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}^2cos^2{\delta}\\+4s_{12}^2s_{23}s_{13}cos{2\theta_{12}})+s_{23}^2s_{13}^2s_{12}(2c_{12}s_{12}^2c_{23}sin{\delta}+c_{23}c_{12}cos{2\theta_{12}}sin{2\delta})^2\\-4c_{12}c_{23}s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}sin{2\delta}sin{\delta}(s_{12}^2+2cos{2\theta_{12}})(2+c_{12}^2))^\frac{1}{2}\end{multlined}}{2s_{12}((-c_{12}s_{12}c_{23}+s_{12}s_{23}s_{13}cos{\delta})^2+s_{12}^2s_{23}^2s_{13}^2sin^2{\delta})}
\end{multlined} $\\ 
\hline
{} & $\begin{multlined}
\rho_{-}=\frac{\begin{multlined}(sin^2{2\theta_{12}}c_{12}^2c_{23}^4+c_{12}^2c_{23}^2s_{23}s_{13}(4c_{23}sin{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}+2s_{23}s_{13}+s_{23}s_{13}cos{2\delta}(1+cos^2{\theta_{12}})\\+2c_{23}sin{2\theta_{12}}cos{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}-8s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}^2cos{\delta}-4s_{12}^2c_{23}sin{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}-4s_{12}^2cos{2\theta_{12}})\\+s_{23}s_{13}^2(2c_{12}c_{23}cos{\delta}+c_{12}c_{23}cos{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}-s_{12}c_{23}sin{2\theta_{12}}cos{\delta}-s_{12}cos{2\theta_{12}})^2\\+s_{23}^2s_{13}^2((s_{12}c_{23}sin{2\theta_{12}}sin{\delta}+c_{12}c_{23}cos{2\theta_{12}}sin{\delta})^2+2s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}^3sin{2\delta}\\(c_{23}s_{12}sin{2\theta_{12}}sin{\delta}+c_{12}c_{23}cos{2\theta_{12}}sin{\delta})))^\frac{1}{2}\end{multlined}}{2s_{12}((-c_{12}s_{12}c_{23}+s_{12}^2s_{23}s_{13}cos{\delta})^2+s_{12}^2s_{23}^2s_{13}^2sin^2{\delta})}
\end{multlined}$


\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And the table is coming in this manner
[image: The table is going outside the page. How to adjust it]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to consider expressing this in a different manner, that does not include a table.

Comment: But I need to write these long expressions in the table, how do I edit it?

Comment: Why do you need it in a table? I'd use `\paragraph{Case $C_{11}:}` and then write this in a suitable display math construction. BTW: please use `\cos`, `\sin` etc

Comment: I agree with @daleif: this stuff simply cannot be presented as table in a meaningful and intelligible way.

Comment: Is it not possible to adjust the expressions in a table? I tried writing paragraph wise as I've a lot of these kind of expressions but it looked clumsy. Thought it would be better to write it in a table. Please help me out if it's possible to make a table with these expressions.

Answer (score 2):

- you should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`
- without MWE is your document layout unknown so we don't know how wide your table can be
- based on assumption, that you use A4 paper size and that text borders are 1in is possible breaking points in `multline` rearranged so, that table not spill-out of document's text area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{$}c<{$}|>{\small $\displaystyle}X<{$}|}
    \hline
\text{Case} & \text{Analytical Expressions}   \\
    \hline\hline
C_{11}      & 
\rho_{+}=\frac{\left[\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
    (\sin^2{2\theta_{12}}c_{12}^2c_{23}^4-s_{13}^2s_{23}^2c_{12}^2c_{23}^2\cos^2{\delta}(2(1+s_{12}^2)-\cos{2\theta_{12}})^2\\
    -c_{12}^2c_{23}^2s_{23}^2s_{13}^2(4c_{23}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta}(1+s_{12}^2)-2s_{23}^2s_{13}\\
    -2c_{23}\cos{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta}-s_{23}s_{13}\cos{2\delta}+s_{23}s_{13}\cos^2{2\theta_{12}}\cos{2\delta}-8s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}^2\cos^2{\delta}\\
    +4s_{12}^2s_{23}s_{13}\cos{2\theta_{12}})+s_{23}^2s_{13}^2s_{12}(2c_{12}s_{12}^2c_{23}\sin{\delta}+c_{23}c_{12}\cos{2\theta_{12}}\sin{2\delta})^2\\
    -4c_{12}c_{23}s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}\sin{2\delta}\sin{\delta}(s_{12}^2+2\cos{2\theta_{12}})(2+c_{12}^2))^\frac{1}{2}
    \end{multlined}\right]}
    {2s_{12}((-c_{12}s_{12}c_{23}+s_{12}s_{23}s_{13}\cos{\delta})^2+s_{12}^2s_{23}^2s_{13}^2\sin^2{\delta})} \\
\hline
            & 
\rho_{-}=\frac{\left[\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
    (\sin^2{2\theta_{12}}c_{12}^2c_{23}^4+c_{12}^2c_{23}^2s_{23}s_{13}(4c_{23}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta} \\
     + 2s_{23}s_{13}+s_{23}s_{13}\cos{2\delta}(1+\cos^2{\theta_{12}})
            +2c_{23}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\cos{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta} \\
     - 8s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}^2\cos{\delta}
            -4s_{12}^2c_{23}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta}-4s_{12}^2\cos{2\theta_{12}}) \\
     + s_{23}s_{13}^2(2c_{12}c_{23}\cos{\delta}+c_{12}c_{23}\cos{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta}-s_{12}c_{23}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\cos{\delta}-s_{12}\cos{2\theta_{12}})^2\\
     + s_{23}^2s_{13}^2((s_{12}c_{23}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\sin{\delta}+c_{12}c_{23}\cos{2\theta_{12}}\sin{\delta})^2\\
     + 2s_{23}s_{13}s_{12}^3\sin{2\delta}(c_{23}s_{12}\sin{2\theta_{12}}\sin{\delta}+c_{12}c_{23}\cos{2\theta_{12}}\sin{\delta})))^\frac{1}{2}
       \end{multlined}\right]}
    {2s_{12}((-c_{12}s_{12}c_{23}+s_{12}^2s_{23}s_{13}\cos{\delta})^2+s_{12}^2s_{23}^2s_{13}^2\sin^2{\delta})} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic:

- in your table code is added `\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells`` which insert small vertical space above and below equations
- `cos` and `sin` are operators, so they are written as `\cos` and `\sin`
- numerators are enclosed by brackets that are more obvious that they are numerators

[image]

**Edid:**
now is considered @egreg comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really grateful

Comment: What's the purpose of the outer `multlined` environments? I'd just use `>{\small $\displaystyle}X<{$}`

Comment: @egreg, you are right. I blindly overtake it from OP. it is removed now. Thank you very much for pointing me to this.